# Where better to escape struct to heap

Tags: go

For example, I have a function that should return a pointer to a structure.
Two examples:

First:

```
type ExampleGrpcMessage struct {
    SomeValue string
}

func GrpcHandler() *ExampleGrpcMessage {
        // ... some code
    test:= FuncTwo()
        // ... some code
    return test
}

//go:noinline
func FuncTwo() *ExampleGrpcMessage {
    return &ExampleGrpcMessage{
        SomeValue: "SomeData",
    }
}
```

Second:

```
type ExampleGrpcMessage struct {
    SomeValue string
}

func GrpcHandler() *ExampleGrpcMessage {
    // ... some code
    test := FuncTwo()
    // ... some code
    return &ExampleGrpcMessage{
        SomeValue: test.SomeValue,
    }
}

type MessageOnStack struct {
    SomeValue string
}

//go:noinline
func FuncTwo() MessageOnStack {
    return MessageOnStack{
        SomeValue: "SomeData",
    }
}
```

In the first example , the structure escapes to heap in `FuncTwo`. In second in `GrpcHandler`. Is there any difference in performance between these examples?

Comment: "Is there any difference in performance between these examples?" Measure. Nobody can tell because it depends on a lot of factors and your code is the most unimportant one here: Compiler used? Platform? Workload? Actual size of data?